Prediction Intervals for forecasts vs Probabilistic Forecasting
In the context of time series forecasting, there a relationship between these 2? Are prediction intervals are type of probabilistic forecasting?

For such a question it is helpful to be precise. What is your understanding of prediction interval? And where does probabilistic forecasting begin for you?
